# C ArrayList crashing

Tags: c, memory-management, data-structures

My arraylist file:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "ArrayList.h"


typedef struct ArrayList {
    uint32_t size;
    void **data;

    uint32_t capacity;
} ArrayList;


ArrayList *arrayList_construct(uint32_t initialCapacity) {
    if (initialCapacity < 10) {
        initialCapacity = 10;
    }
    ArrayList *arrayList = malloc(sizeof(ArrayList));
    arrayList->size = 0;
    arrayList->capacity = initialCapacity;
    arrayList->data = malloc(initialCapacity * sizeof(void *));
    return arrayList;
}

void arrayList_add(ArrayList *arrayList, void *item) {
    ensureCapacity(arrayList);
    *(arrayList->data + arrayList->size) = item;
    arrayList->size++;
}

void arrayList_set(ArrayList *arrayList, uint32_t index, void *value) {
    *(arrayList->data + index) = value;
}

void *arrayList_get(ArrayList *arrayList, uint32_t index) {
    return *(arrayList->data + index);
}

void arrayList_remove(ArrayList *arrayList, uint32_t index) {
    memcpy(arrayList->data + index, arrayList->data + index + 1, (arrayList->size - index - 1) * sizeof(void *));
    free(*(arrayList->data + arrayList->size-- - 1));
}

uint32_t arrayList_getSize(ArrayList *arrayList) {
    return arrayList->size;
}

void arrayList_destruct(ArrayList *arrayList) {
    free(arrayList->data);
    free(arrayList);
}

static void ensureCapacity(ArrayList *arrayList) {
    if (arrayList->size >= arrayList->capacity) {
        uint32_t oldCapacity = arrayList->capacity;
        uint32_t newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1) * 2;
        arrayList->capacity = newCapacity;

        void **newSpace = malloc(sizeof(void *) * newCapacity);
        void **oldSpace = arrayList->data;
        arrayList->data = memcpy(newSpace, oldSpace, oldCapacity);
        free(oldSpace);
    }
}

int main() {
    ArrayList *arrayList = arrayList_construct((uint32_t) 10);


    int *array = malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        *(array + i) = i;
        arrayList_add(arrayList, array + i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList_getSize(arrayList); i++) {
        printf("[%p]: %d\n", arrayList_get(arrayList, i), *(int *) arrayList_get(arrayList, i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The arraylist works fine when I put 10 objects in it.
But it crashes (memory access violation) when I put more objects in it (100).
It prints the first 2 objects and then it crashes.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Why aren't you using [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)?

Comment: How big is your heap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely how you copy the memory:

```
memcpy(newSpace, oldSpace, oldCapacity);
```

The third argument is the size *in bytes*. You need to multiply this with `sizeof(void *)` to get the correct size.

Comment: If I destruct this arraylist, do I need to free every element too?

Comment: @user2997204 I would say it's not the responsibility of the arraylist or its destructor function, but for the user of it. What if the pointers in the list point to data not allocated dynamically on the heap?

Answer (score 0):

When you already know the size of your arrylist, the better option to declare an arrylist would be

```
ArrayList *arrayList[size]
```

but if you do not know size then a preferred way would be to use linked list. i.e create an element and attach it to your list.

Another thing that can be useful in your current state is to use

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size)
```

instead of using malloc in ensureCapacity function.